# Can't Connect to wifi 5.3.0-62-generic

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm using a T430 Thinkpad laptop with 5.3.0-62-generic Ubuntu on it. Today I could connect to
my home network in the morning. But in the evening aka now, I cannot, due to an error, which according to dmesg is this (sorry if there's output that's not neccessary, this is my first post on here):

```
audit: type=1107 audit(1595014020.261:196): pid=1051 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.12" mask="receive" pid=2401 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=1057 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  477.870889] audit: type=1107 audit(1595014065.447:197): pid=1051 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.12" mask="receive" pid=2401 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=1057 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  477.870985] audit: type=1107 audit(1595014065.447:198): pid=1051 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.12" mask="receive" pid=2401 label="snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop" peer_pid=1057 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  477.871464] wlan0: deauthenticating from bc:ee:7b:65:f4:80 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

Edit: As asked by user guiverc, release details are provided here:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Almost forgot to mention, I can still connect to a wifi-hotspot that I create with my phone, but can't connect to my home network

Comment: Maybe relevant? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386925/aborting-authentication-by-local-choice-reason-3-deauth-leaving-when-trying

Comment: But the `msg='apparmor="DENIED"` might be the key.

Comment: I have tried what the link you sent suggests, sadly didn't help. And yeah, I'm not sure how it might be the key, I'm quite the newbie when it comes to Linux and reading output like this.

Comment: Support for wifi cards is one of the biggest weaknesses with Linux unfortunately, there must be hundreds if not thousands of unanswered questions on here. I hope someone is able to help.

Comment: Yeah, I'm hoping for the same thing.  My guess is that the issue is that the laptop, or the drivers don't get access to some folder or file that stores the authentication, so it's got no choice but to deauthenticate. But I'm probably wrong in that(That's judging from the ' msg='apparmor="DENIED" ' output beforehand, but it doesn't quite work out logically, since I can still connect to a wi-fi hotspot created from my phone)

Comment: If you have Broadcom wifi, you might need to set the router to channel 1-11 on 2.4 GHz

Comment: @guiverc Edited the question to add the information requested

Comment: @Jeremy31 Not using Broadcom wifi, European ISP, router's been messed around with in that sense way before I started to become interested in tech, so I'm pretty sure that's already been done

Comment: I don't think you connecting to the wifi has to do with that error message... I mean, it's specific to telegram desktop